# UBoot binary file strcture and offsets

Tags: u-boot

I believe the UBoot binary image has a common format
, containing following fields:

```
------------------------------------------
| Header: UBoot version, code size, ...  |
------------------------------------------
| code                                   |
------------------------------------------
|  A Queue maybe containing CRC          |
------------------------------------------
```

Can you please help me find the offsets of each field ? The most important for me is the offsets of the header parameters (version, entry point, ...), so any documentation would be helpful.

I saw [this structure](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/include/image.h#L349) in uboot code, but I am not sure if these are the correct header offsets since it is not matching with the uboot.bin generated in my case. Is it maybe platform dependent ?

Comment: *"I believe the UBoot binary image has a common format ..."* -- Incorrect.  The image file of the U-Boot executable is whatever a standalone program for the given CPU architecture requires.  The header you reference is for the images that U-Boot can load into memory, and does not apply to U-Boot itself.

Comment: hmmm, you are right that make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the U-Boot version string you can use:

```
grep -a 'U-Boot [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]' u-boot.bin
```

u-boot.bin is a raw file which is typically the concatenation of multiple files. The layout of the binaries is defined by linker scripts like arch/arm/cpu/armv8/u-boot.lds. Typically the entry point is on the first byte.

Comment: allright, yes you are right, I can confirm that the entrypoint is the 1st Byte, I used readelf to know the entrypoint offset in the elf and yes it is matching the first Byte in the binary,

Comment: One more question I have, Is it possible to extract the binary size from u-boot binary ?

Comment: ls -la u-boot.bin gives you the file size. What else do you mean by binary size?